# Respecting user css overrides, etc., within SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, accessibility

I would like to put some simple SVG diagrams on a web page, and for that SVG content to adopt the background and stroke colours of the surrounding text -- *without* relying on some kind of site-building technology that will hard-code everything.  If the user has personal CSS overrides, or a dark-mode plugin, or whatever, I want to pick that up and use it.

It seems like in an ideal world if I just don't specify then that should happen automatically, but it doesn't.  The stroke colour for SVG can be set with `stroke` but that doesn't adopt from the `color` value of plain text.

So far all I've come up with is a bit of javascript to copy the value across:

```js
function fixSVGStroke() {
  for (img of document.getElementsByTagName("svg")) {
    style = getComputedStyle(img);
    img.style.stroke = style.color;
    // img.style.background = style.background;  // doesn't work?
  }
}
```

```css
svg { stroke-width:2; fill-opacity:0.35; }
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) { svg { stroke:black; } }
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { svg { stroke:white; } }
```

```html
</svg>
<button onclick="fixSVGStroke()">Fix me!</button>
<div>
  sample text
  <svg width="180" height="40" id="testpattern">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15" fill="grey"/>
    <circle cx="60" cy="20" r="15" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="20" r="15" fill="green"/>
    <circle cx="140" cy="20" r="15" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>
  (default colours)
</div>
<div style="color:yellow; background:navy">
  sample text
  <svg width="180" height="40">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15" fill="grey"/>
    <circle cx="60" cy="20" r="15" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="20" r="15" fill="green"/>
    <circle cx="140" cy="20" r="15" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>
  (yellow/navy)
</div>
<div style="color:maroon; background:silver">
  sample text
  <svg width="180" height="40">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15" fill="grey"/>
    <circle cx="60" cy="20" r="15" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="20" r="15" fill="green"/>
    <circle cx="140" cy="20" r="15" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>
  (maroon/silver)
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

If not, where's the right place to put the hook for my fix-up function?  Somewhere it can cooperate with user overrides and dark-mode plugins?

Ideally I would respect the user's choice to not run JavaScript by default.  I included the `@media (prefers-color-scheme: *)` thing to ensure a tolerable default (as shown), but that turned out to be counterproductive.  The host page may not be respecting the same setting, and if I manually force a background colour to match the foreground colour, then I can't seem to fix it up in JavaScript the way I fix the stroke colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [`currentcolor` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentcolor_keyword), as described on the MDN Web docs:

> The `currentcolor` keyword represents the value of an element's [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) property. This lets you use the `color` value on properties that do not receive it by default.

```css
svg {
  stroke-width:2;
  fill-opacity:0.35;
  stroke: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div>
  sample text
  <svg width="180" height="40" id="testpattern">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15" fill="grey"/>
    <circle cx="60" cy="20" r="15" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="20" r="15" fill="green"/>
    <circle cx="140" cy="20" r="15" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>
  (default colours)
</div>
<div style="color:yellow; background:navy">
  sample text
  <svg width="180" height="40">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15" fill="grey"/>
    <circle cx="60" cy="20" r="15" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="20" r="15" fill="green"/>
    <circle cx="140" cy="20" r="15" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>
  (yellow/navy)
</div>
<div style="color:maroon; background:silver">
  sample text
  <svg width="180" height="40">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15" fill="grey"/>
    <circle cx="60" cy="20" r="15" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="20" r="15" fill="green"/>
    <circle cx="140" cy="20" r="15" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>
  (maroon/silver)
</div>
```